# C++ erro:undefined reference to `EnumProcesses@12

Tags: c++, eclipse, process

I'm trying to get list of running processes with [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However when I try to compile I receive this exception:

```
Undefined reference to `EnumProcesses@12'
```

I'm using eclipse Mingw and XP.

I have tried adding `-lpsapi` option but it seems not work.

This is code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int main() {
    DWORD pid[100], bytesr;
    EnumProcesses(pid, sizeof(pid), &bytesr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read http://sscce.org/ and then update your question to show us the code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: It seems, you are not linking with the library that has this function. It might be in `kernel32.dll` (which you should be linking with anyway), but it also might be in `psapi.dll`. Check `PSAPI_VERSION` from `psapi.h`. If it's `1` you should be linking with `psapi.dll`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated first post and I will try with your instructions.

Comment: Do you specify `-lpsapi` at the right place in the command line? The MinGW linker requires that libraries providing functions are specified **after** the objects/libraries requiring them, i.e. you probably should put the option very close to the end of the command line.

Comment: I'm not sure if I do it correctly. I added -lpsapi from eclipse project->propeties->GCC C++ Compiler->miscellaneous and added it to other flags box and it i receive same error message. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Tom It belongs on the *linker* flags, not the compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify as this may be a bit confusing for beginners.

In the case of **Qt**, you need to add this to your .pro file

```
win32:LIBS += -lpsapi
```

*another example is to add the kernel32 library to your project, use:*

```
win32:LIBS += -lkernel32
```

Hope this can help someone